# How to use c++ module in gstreamer plugin?

Tags: c++, c, plugins, gstreamer, libraries

I need to include algorithm written in C++ into my gstreamer plugin.
I've created algorithm.h file, which holds

```
extern "C" int myFunction( );
```

and algorithm algorithm.cpp file which implements this function.
Now after I built & install my plugin, which includes the algorithm.h file and calls myFunction(), I tried to run test pipeline with my element, which resulted in error telling me that there is no myFunction object.

I suppose this has something to do with not including object module with myFunction into the plugin's binary file. Thus my question is:

**How to properly use my c++ module with my plugin?**

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to use my c++ module in my plugin by using this tutorial: [link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/include-c-hdrs-nonsystem.html).

I also needed to include some flags in configure.ac file.

```
17 dnl enable mainainer mode by default
18 AM_MAINTAINER_MODE([enable])
19 
20 dnl check for tools (compiler etc.)
21 AC_PROG_CC
22 AC_PROG_CXX         // <-- 22, 23 lines were included.
23 AC_PROG_LIBTOOL     // <-- |
24 
25 dnl required version of libtool
26 LT_PREREQ([2.2.6])
27 LT_INIT
```

This allowed me to compile and run my c++ function from my plugin's code.
However I'm still experiencing problems if I try to include  header file in my c++ code. The problem is that this module is compiled without gstreamer's dependencies, and I can't figure out how to set it properly.